# Guava getTopLevelClasses in Netbeans module fails to find classes

Tags: java, netbeans, module, guava

I'm trying to use Guava to find all classes of in a package in a module/plugin in Netbeans using this pattern:

```
ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
Set<ClassPath.ClassInfo> classesInPackage = ClassPath.from(cl).getTopLevelClassesRecursive(pack);
```

It works well when testing it inside the project, but when deploying the module it always comes up with 0 classes. I've tried various types of ClassLoaders, System and Thread.currentThread but with the same result. I've found a known issue related to this, but it is for Java 9 and supposedly fixed.

The classes are there. I currently use:

```
ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
Class c = cl.loadClass(className);
```

to load a number of them manually.

Edit: I use Java 8 and Guava 22

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather simple in the end. I solved it by using a new URLClassloader as "cl". In my specific case, I was loading an additional jar on the classpath which "cl" was linked to.

Don't forget to set a parent.